# apt-get not working on my Ubuntu Desktop  9.04 jaunty since this morning 

Tags: apt, repository

Since this morning I am not able to use apt-get command on my Ubuntu 9.04
It's throwing the following error :

> W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jaunty/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404 Not Found

I think Ubuntu changed its repository link and my `/etc/apt/source.list` did not update accordingly.

Is anybody here facing same problem ?

Comment: I got this problem also , and i didn't know yet how to resolve it or how Chang the line in the sources.list file cause I don't know where the line is , I'm new to to Linux , so if there any help please share it with us

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you could change your repository temporarily for an other?
Try to replace the "in.", i suppose it will work fine.
You'll put it again after.

Comment: @vinayrks: Then probably you should consider to accept the answer proposed by Matthieu and give him some rep... ;)